# pivoting data wide -- how to summarize data based on multiple columns?

Tags: r, pivot, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I am looking at the number of witnesses that testify on pieces of legislation. I currently have a dataset like this:

```
df <- data.frame(bill_number = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4),
witness_id= c("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5", "Name6", "Name7", "Name8", "Name9", "Name10", "Name11", "Name12", "Name13"),
witness_race = c("Black", "White", "White", "Black", "White", "White", "White", "Asian", "White", "White White", "Black", "Black", "White"),
witness_gender = c("Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female"))
```

I want to pivot my data wide to be on the "bill level" (one row for each bill number), but I would like to summarize the wide data into counts: "number of witnesses", "number of female witnesses", "number of male witnesses", "number of white witnesses", "number of black witnesses" etc.

My desired result would be a dataset like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(bill_number = c(1,2,3,4),
number_white_witnesses = c(2, 2, 3, 1),
number_black_witnesses = c(2, 0, 0, 2),
number_asian_witnesses = c(0, 0, 1, 0),
number_female_witnesses = c(1, 1, 1, 3),
number_male_witnesses = c(3, 1, 3, 0))
```

Any idea on how to approach this?
I am an R novice, but am familiar with the Tidyverse package.

Comment: your data has one "White White" value (a good example of why factors variables are better than strings in this case! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest working with the two sets independently and then join them.

```r
tmp1 <- count(df, bill_number, witness_gender) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = bill_number, names_from = witness_gender, values_from = n, names_glue = "number_{witness_gender}_witnesses")
tmp2 <- count(df, bill_number, witness_race) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = bill_number, names_from = witness_race, values_from = n, names_glue = "number_{witness_race}_witnesses")
full_join(tmp1, tmp2, by = "bill_number")
# # A tibble: 4 × 7
#   bill_number number_Female_witnesses number_Male_witnesses number_Black_witnesses number_White_witnesses number_Asian_witnesses `number_White White_witnesses`
#         <dbl>                   <int>                 <int>                  <int>                  <int>                  <int>                          <int>
# 1           1                       1                     3                      2                      2                     NA                             NA
# 2           2                       1                     1                     NA                      2                     NA                             NA
# 3           3                       1                     3                     NA                      2                      1                              1
# 4           4                       3                    NA                      2                      1                     NA                             NA
```

Comment: yes, but I didn't want to assume cleaning of the data yet, inferring from the inconsistency of the OP sample data that all-lower-case was merely a convenience for the question

Answer (score 0):

r2evans's answer is great, but if for whatever reason you don't want to use a full_join, here's another way:

```
df |>
  select(-witness_id) |>
  pivot_longer(-bill_number) |>
  pivot_wider(values_fn = length, names_from = value, id_cols = bill_number, values_fill = 0, names_glue = "number_{tolower(value)}_witnesses")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 7
  bill_number number_black_witnesses number_male_witnesses
        <dbl>                  <int>                 <int>
1           1                      2                     3
2           2                      0                     1
3           3                      0                     3
4           4                      2                     0
  number_white_witnesses number_female_witnesses number_asian_witnesses
                   <int>                   <int>                  <int>
1                      2                       1                      0
2                      2                       1                      0
3                      2                       1                      1
4                      1                       3                      0
  `number_white white_witnesses`
                           <int>
1                              0
2                              0
3                              1
4                              0
```